# Refresh multiselect dropdown dynamically in jqgrid edit

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jqgrid

I am trying to populate a multiselect dropdown dynamically in jqgrid edit. The jqgrid has two dropdowns namely, role and roletype. The roletype options should change as per the option selected in role. However, though the ajax call gets new values on role drop down change event, the roletype does not refresh. The code is as follows:

```
var selRoleVal;

var mygrid = $("#MyGrid"),
         ...
   , getRoleTypes = function () {
        var roleTypeData;

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Page/GetDefinitions",               
            data: "{'roleID': '" + selRoleVal + "'}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            async: false,
            success: function (json) {
                roleTypeData = json;
            },
            error: function (json) {
                alert("Failed ...");
            }
        });
        return roleTypeData;

    }

    , setRoleTypeValues = function (role) {

        mygrid.jqGrid('setColProp', 'RoleType', {
            editoptions: {
                value: function (elem) {
                   var roleTypeData;

                    roleTypeData = getRoleType();
                    return roleTypeData;
                }
                , recreateForm: true

            }

        });

    };



mygrid.jqGrid({
        ...,            
        colNames: ['ID', 'Role', 'Role Type'],
        colModel: [
                    { name: 'id', index: 'id', width: 20, editable: false,     editoptions: { readonly: true, size: 1 } },                        
                    {
                        name: 'RoleName', index: 'RoleName', align: "center", width:   80, sortable: true, editable: true, edittype: "select", stype: "select",
                        searchoptions: {
                            value: RoleList
                        },
                        editoptions: {
                            value: RoleList,
                            dataInit: function (elem) {
                                selRoleVal = $(elem).val();
                            },
                            dataEvents: [{
                                type: 'change',
                                fn: function (e) {
                                     selRoleVal = $(e.target).val();
                                    setRoleTypeValues($(e.target).val());
                                 }
                            }]

                        }
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'RoleType', index: 'RoleType', width: 100, sortable: true, editable: true, edittype: "select", 
                         editoptions: {
                             value: getRoleType
                                 ,
                            dataInit: function (elem) {
                                    $(elem).multiselect({
                                        minWidth: 80, 
                                        height: 200,
                                        selectedList: 10,
                                        checkAllText: "Check all",
                                        uncheckAllText: "Uncheck all",
                                        noneSelectedText: "Any",
                                        open: function () {
                                            var $menu = $(".ui-multiselect-menu:visible");
                                            $menu.width("auto");
                                            return;
                                        }


                                    })

                                    $(elem).multiselect('refresh');

                            },
                            multiple: true
                        }
                    }

        ],
        rowNum: 20,
        rowList: [20, 40, 60],
        ...
        editurl: ...

        ....

    }).jqGrid('navGrid', '#MyPager', {
        ....
        , edit: true
        , add: true
        , del: true
        , search: false
        , recreateForm: true 
    })
```

What should I include to refresh roletype dropdown ?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the first item in the discussion section of http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:common_rules, it demonstrates how you can reference the roletype select from the role select. Try something like this.

```
setRoleTypeValues = function (roleSelect, role) {

    var roleTypeSelect = roleSelect.closest("tr").find("select#RoleType");
    roleTypeSelect.empty().html(roleTypeDataOptionsAsHtml); 
    roleTypeSelect.multiselect('refresh');
    });

};

               {
                    name: 'RoleName', index: 'RoleName', align: "center", width:   80, sortable: true, editable: true, edittype: "select", stype: "select",
                    searchoptions: {
                        value: RoleList
                    },
                    editoptions: {
                        value: RoleList,
                        dataInit: function (elem) {
                            selRoleVal = $(elem).val();
                        },
                        dataEvents: [{
                            type: 'change',
                            fn: function (e) {
                                 selRoleVal = $(e.target).val();
                                setRoleTypeValues($(e.target), $(e.target).val());
                             }
                        }]

                    }
                },
```

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I am using multiselect widget at [this link](http://www.erichynds.com/blog/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget). I tried your suggested method by building a select html in dataevents of role column; however, the dropdown did not refresh. Probably, it has to do something with the way control is being found. I used `var roleTypeCtrl = $("select#RoleType");                                       roleTypeCtrl.empty().html(roleTypeOptions);`

Comment: That will work, but I chose to use roleSelect.closest("tr").find("select#RoleType"); because its possible to have two rows editable at the same time.

Comment: Was not able to find the right control. So used `var rowid = mygrid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow'); $("select[id='" + rowid + "_RoleType']").empty().append(roleTypeOptions).multiselect();` as per the firefox firebug to get the correct element. Thanks for the idea !!

Comment: likely have to use $(e.target[0]) in order to find the correct tr, but your way works...